# Python Logging module not respecting setLevel below '30' (Warning)?

Tags: python, logging, python-3.3

I'm at a bit of a loss here. I could swear that I had this working earlier last week. Today I've returned to it and can't seem to get logging to work.

In the below sample script, I hope to show a relatively complete demonstration of my issue.

**test.py**

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
print("Logger currently at level '{0}'".format(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
logger.warning("Testing Warning")
logger.setLevel(60)
print("Logger currently at level '{0}'".format(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
logger.error("Testing Error")
logger.setLevel(50)
print("Logger currently at level '{0}'".format(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
logger.error("Testing Error")
logger.setLevel(40)
print("Logger currently at level '{0}'".format(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
logger.error("Testing Error")
logger.setLevel(30)
print("Logger currently at level '{0}'".format(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
logger.info("Testing Info")
logger.setLevel(20)
print("Logger currently at level '{0}'".format(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
logger.info("Testing Info")
logger.setLevel(10)
print("Logger currently at level '{0}'".format(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
logger.info("Testing Info")
logger.setLevel(0)
print("Logger currently at level '{0}'".format(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
logger.info("Testing Info")
```

**output**

```
Logger currently at level '30'
Testing Warning
Logger currently at level '60'
Logger currently at level '50'
Logger currently at level '40'
Testing Error
Logger currently at level '30'
Logger currently at level '20'
Logger currently at level '10'
Logger currently at level '0'
```

I have no idea why the logging module is acting differently, considering I'm using [this](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules) official documentation to try and make it happen. You can see near the end how it's blatantly ignoring the level for `logger`. Am I somehow bypassing `logger` and instead logging against a default? I don't understand.

Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add a handler to your logger. On Python 3.3 (and later), if no handler is specified, an internal ["handler of last resort"](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/logging.html#logging.lastResort), which has a level of `WARNING`, is used. So even though your messages are sent through the logger, they are discarded by the internal handler (which is only there to catch misconfigurations). On Python 2.x, you would have got a one-off message printed to `stderr` - `No handlers could be found for logger "root"`.

If you add a line

```
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

before the first print, you will get behaviour like this:

```
Logger currently at level '30'
Testing Warning
Logger currently at level '60'
Logger currently at level '50'
Logger currently at level '40'
Testing Error
Logger currently at level '30'
Logger currently at level '20'
Testing Info
Logger currently at level '10'
Testing Info
Logger currently at level '0'
Testing Info
```

**Update:** There is no need to "add a handler manually" - this was just the easiest way to illustrate what the problem was. You can use `basicConfig()` to configure logging simply (console or file, limited options) or use[`dictConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) to configure more flexibly. These methods work in the same way across Python 2.7 and 3.2 (and later).

Comment: Thank you! This worked splendidly. And I learned something new. I am used to Python 2 more than 3, but also used to Java more than Python.

Is "attach a handler manually" a standard approach to EVERYTHING in Python 3?

Comment: Excellent addendum! I'll read more into this, and thanks very much!